# Ошибка линковшика "unresolved external"

Tags: c++builder-xe, c++

Объясните, пожалуйста, следующий эффект: присоединяю к проекту .cpp файл вместе с заголовочным. Все прекрасно компилируется, но линковщик выдает ошибку  "Unresolved external...". Если же я присоединяю вместо этих двух файлов объектный модуль, скомпилированный из них же, то все компилируется и линкуется как песня.

Comment: Если бы дали больше деталей. Может, компилируете по разному, или компилятор настроен специфически в проекте.

Comment: Данный род ошибок однозначно сообщает, что компилятор не видит реализацию объявленных конструкций. Но делать он это может по тысяче причин. Попробуйте добавить cpp+header с очень простым одним методом, посмотрите результат. Потом добавляйте по чуть-чуть, проверяя, что ошибки нет. В процессе Вы увидите, чего не хватает.

Comment: Уважаемый @KoVadim, не представляю себе, какие именно детали следует дать, чтобы все стало ясным. Могу уточнить лишь, что добавляемые файлы содержат класс MATRIX, созданный из std::vector.

Уважаемый @smallFish, спасибо, конечно, но в том-то и дело, что проект компилируется успешно. Ошибка вылезает при линковке.

Comment: @BuilderC, Вы правы, я имел ввиду линкер, а не компилятор.